# Getting user information issue in Botman studio

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, botman

I'm using botman studio and facebook driver with facebook Api graph 8.0 and I'm trying to get user information by using:

```
    $botman->hears('GET_START', function ($bot) {
    $user = $bot->getUser();
    $firstname = $user->getFirstname();
    $bot->reply($firstname); });
```

but no i get this error :

(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

Can any one help me with this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code
you have a few mistakes

```
$botman->hears('code', function ($bot) {
$user = $bot->getUser();
$firstname = $user->getFirstName();
$lastname = $user->getLastName();
$userId = $user->getId();
$bot->reply($firstname . '  ' . $userId);});
```

it's should work